# Visual Basic 2010 How to search database based on selection from 2 combobox

Tags: vb.net

I am doing airline reservation system here
I want to ask the user to choose the departure (combobox1) and destination (combobox2), and the system will read this 2 selection, the check with the database and show the available flight in the `DataGridView`.

The problem, how to set the search result will only show the flight that is based on combobox1 and combobox2?

This is the syntax I have made:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

FlightDataGridView.DataSource = Me.FlightsDatabaseDataSet.Flight.Select("Departure= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'")

FlightDataGridView.DataSource = Me.FlightsDatabaseDataSet.Flight.Select("Destination= '" & ComboBox2.Text & "'")
```

The result is:

[image]

As per the picture show, I want only the flight where the departure is Kuala Lumpur and Destination is Osaka, but it will show all the flight where destination is Osaka even the departure is not Kuala Lumpur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [SQL AND](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) statement. Something like:

```
FlightDataGridView.DataSource = Me.FlightsDatabaseDataSet.Flight.Select("Departure= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' AND Destination= '" & ComboBox2.Text & "'"")
```

Comment: Hi Disk, thank you, it work, can i ask you another question? The search result do not show the date and time, it only show departure , destination and price, what's wrong?

Comment: @ZephaniahChua Those fields probably aren't included in the original dataset. Not enough information here to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi Disk, it is included, before click on search button, the datagrid can show every details, but once i click the search button, the result it search is only showing the departure, destination, and price.

Comment: @ZephaniahChua Again, not enough information here to productively troubleshoot. You should select this answer and post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

2nd statement for selecting the DataSource is updating the 1st statement. Combine the condition in one statement.